# whats the return type of .getClass() method...is it class name or object of class?

Tags: java

whats the return type of .getClass() method...is it class name or object of class??
     and whats the return type of .forName()..
     and whats the difference between .forName("Myclasss") return type and Myclass 
     have browsed about it and got really confused
     Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's important to understand that `MyClass` and `String` and, for that matter, `Class` does not refer to an object, at least not in the same way that `myReferenceToAString` would refer to an object.  It is merely a way to identify a class to the compiler, and does not "exist" as an object or reference (or any other entity) at runtime.

Comment: Thanks buddy...can u plz let me know the difference between .getclass() and .forName() apart from the fact that one uses object and other uses class name

Comment: That's it.  You use the first if you want to find out the class of an object.  You use the second if you simply want the Class object for a named class.

Answer (score 2):

`getClass()` returns an instance of [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which represents the type of the object it was called on. `Class.forName(String)` is a static method in `java.lang.Class` which returns an instance of `java.lang.Class` which fully qualified name was passed as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks buddy...can u plz let me know the difference between .getclass() and .forName() apart from the fact that one uses object and other uses class name

Answer (score 0):

The `getClass()` gets the class of an object at runtime. So if you have an object in your application and want to check of what class it is - then you can use `myObject.getClass()` method. By later invoking the `getName()` or `getCanonicalName()` you can get the name of that class.

On the other hand, when you know the name of a class then you can use `Class.forName('yourPackage.yourClassName')`.
So both of those methods return the same type, but one is used to get the Class of your object at runtime, and the second is used to get the Class with a given name.
In both cases you may use the returned Class object to invoke an object of this Class, get it's fields, methods etc. using reflection.